# How to customize learner profile in OpenEdx?

Tags: django, openedx

I managed to customize some templates in lms, but now I need to customize learner profile. I know how to overwrite learner_profile.scss, but I have trouble with html template. I found learner_profile.html template in location outside of lms directory: `openedx/features/learner_profile/templates/learner_profile/learner_profile.html`
I have tried to overwrite it with:

- `themes/my-theme/openedx/features/learner_profile/templates/learner_profile/learner_profile.html`
- `themes/my-theme/openedx/templates/features/learner_profile/learner_profile.html`
- `themes/my-theme/lms/features/learner_profile/learner_profile.html`

None of these paths worked. How can I do that?

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: hello @ann.piv do you succeed in implementing custom profile ?

Answer (score 0):

you just follow the same path starting from templates directory
your path becomes
theme/theme-name/lms/template/learner_profile/learner_profile.html

Comment: give an example code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).